# How can the code be optimized? The execution takes too long. It recalls API to retrieve many stock prices and writes those prices into a table

Tags: python, sqlite, optimization, query-optimization

```
import requests
from database_utils import connect_to_database

class Tick:
    def __init__(self):
        self.symbol = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.last = 0.0
        self.high = 0.0

def tickprice(code):
    url = f"http://qt.gtimg.cn/q={code}"
    # print(f"API URL: {url}")

    headers = {
        'If-None-Match': '1'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    # print(f"API Response: {response}")

    data = response.split('~')
    # print(f"API Data: {data}")

    if len(data) >= 34:
        tick = Tick()
        tick.last = float(data[3])
       

        return tick

    return None

# Connect to the database
conn, cursor = connect_to_database()

try:
    # Execute the SELECT statement to extract specific columns from the stocks table
    cursor.execute("SELECT stockCode, shsz FROM stocks")

    # Fetch the result
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # Convert rows to dictionaries
    results = []
    column_names = [description[0] for description in cursor.description]  # Extract column names

    # print("Retrieved rows:")
    for row in rows:
        # print(row)

        result = dict(zip(column_names, row))
        results.append(result)

        # Access 'stockCode' from the dictionary
        stock_code = result['stockCode'].strip()
        market = result['shsz']  # Convert market to a string
        if market is None:
            continue  # Skip the iteration if market is None
        if market == 1:
            market = "sh"
        if market == 0:
            market = "sz"
        # print(market)
        stock_code = market + stock_code
        # print(stock_code)
        # Retrieve stock prices using tickprice function
        tick = tickprice(stock_code)
        if tick is not None:
            # Update the stock price in the dictionary
            result['price'] = tick.last

    # Update all stock prices in a single database transaction
    for result in results:
        stock_code = result['stockCode']
        price = result['price']
        cursor.execute("UPDATE stocks SET price=%s WHERE stockCode=%s", (price, stock_code))

    # Commit the changes
    conn.commit()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the cursor and database connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

print("Execution completed.")
```

Comment: Try multithreading your *tickprice()* function

Comment: Multithreading is for a CPU bound program, this is an I/O bound program.

Comment: You are mistaken. Multithreading is well suited to I/O bound activities. Multiprocessing is better suited to CPU intensive functionality

Comment: Are Asyncio and aiohttp a better option?

Comment: Possibly, yes. You'll only know if you code for different techniques and measure the results. There are all sorts of factors that could influence behaviour. My first call would be multithreading because it's easy. If that doesn't give you the benefits that you would have hoped for then move on to async